Vue Chart.JS plugin-annotation throwing error: Cannot find module 'chartjs-plugin-annotation' or its corresponding type declarations
I am having trouble configuring chartjs-plugin-annotation.
I have it setup as a dependency in my vue project as well as chart.js
Versions:
"chart.js": "^4.4.2",
"chartjs-plugin-annotation": "^3.0.1",
Any ideas on how to fix this? If not, is there better chart libraries for vue that I could use ?

import annotationPlugin from 'chartjs-plugin-annotation';

Chart.register(annotationPlugin);


I get the following error:
Cannot find module 'chartjs-plugin-annotation' or its corresponding type declarations.
I tried many different ways of importing it but nothing works. Does anyone know if they still support this or if there is an existing issue? I couldn't seem to find almost anything recent about it.

Is there any more code to that file? Where are you instantiating/importing Chart from?

Hi, Try installing the types for chartjs-plugin-annotation. https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/chartjs-plugin-annotation

@Skandog import { Chart } from "chart.js";

@YashMaheshwari I installed it, but seem to still get the same error.

To ensure it installed also, this is in package.json
"@types/chartjs-plugin-annotation": "^0.5.5",
@YashMaheshwari

@YashMaheshwari sorry but one last thing:
I also tried this: import * as ChartJsAnnotation from "chartjs-plugin-annotation";
And i still get the error: "Cannot find module 'chartjs-plugin-annotation' or its corresponding type declarations."
